# How to reduce unity android game size?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Hello buddies I just build my first demo project in unity just for learning purpose and the size of apk file was 21 mb so how can I reduce my apk size?
I have seen many games that have size less than 5 mb, how do they build these kind of game? 
Do they use some different game engines?
Thanks

Comment: Also you can check [AssetBundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assets are the most likely candidates for optimization. This information is available in the Editor Log just after you have performed the build. Go to the Console window
(menu: Window < Console), click the small drop-down panel in the top right, and select Open Editor Log.

The Editor Log just after a build:

[image]

Suggestions for reducing build size

- **Textures**: select the Texture in the Project view, and in the Inspector
  window reduce the Max Size.
- **Meshes and Animations**: set the Mesh Compression to Low, Medium or High. Mesh and Animation compression uses quantization, which means it takes less space, but the compression can introduce some inaccuracies. Experiment with what level of compression is acceptable for your models.
- **Reducing mobile .NET library size**: ou should avoid any dependencies on System.dll or System.Xml.dll. Unity does not include these in the built player by default, but if you use their classes, they are included. These DLLs add about a megabyte to the player’s storage size. If you need to parse XML in your game, you can use a library like Mono.Xml.zip as a smaller alternative to the system libraries. While most Generic containers are contained in mscorlib, Stack and few others are in System.dll, so you should avoid these if possible.

Refer to [this link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) for more details.

Comment: Good answer, mostly liked dll part. My APK includes System.XML, however, i do not use System.XML anywhere, but i do use  `using System.Linq;`. Not sure how do i trace why unity adds the System.XML. When i remove System.XML forcly from the APK i cannot install the APK.

Comment: a bit too late, yes, but just in case anyone bumped into this issue, Unity WILL NOT include a code just because it's in the `using` section. it checks if it's being used at all. it comes with both mono and il2cpp

Answer (score 1):

of course you can override image size for android , but i recommend you to build under arm v7 architecture , not x86 + armv7 , there are few mobile phone now that uses x86 architecture , you can reduce you game until 11mb , In build section change architecture . If i answered your question please mark as answered

Comment: I downloaded flappy bird game from the internet and its less than 3 mb how???
how they reduce game size this much? Like puzzle games are usually have size less than 15 mb, and they have many stages etc.
How?

Comment: yes of course but  unity3d is game engine not framework or library line libjdx(java) , other library are much native for android meaning written in c++ or java, Unity3d uses C#(mono) and he need additional  tools to run . Thank you